# Cannot select using XPath in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am currently screen scraping using Nokogiri. Although I can select an element using the Chrome plugin "Xpath Helper" I am unable to systematically select it using Nokogiri.

On http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=20-03-2016&venue=ST&raceno=1 I'm trying to traverse all the rows of the table called with the id `'detailWPTable'` and pull out the column data.

In Rails' console, I do the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

html_data = open("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=20-03-2016&venue=ST&raceno=1").read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_data)
entries = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'detailWPTable')]/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]")
```

However, when I look at the `entries` array, it is empty, `[]`.

Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need the minimal input HTML necessary to demonstrate the problem IN THE QUESTION, not as a link we have to retrieve and scan through. Help us help you as we also help others in the future.

Comment: When starting a scraping project, it's always a great idea to use `wget` or `curl` or `nokogiri some_url` to look at the raw HTML, and not trust what you see in a browser. Browsers do a lot of things prior to displaying a page, including fixing up the HTML and executing any DHTML, both of which can affect the HTML you see if you use the browser's source view.

Answer (score 0):

your div with id detailWPTable and tables isnt available when you read with open-uri.

```
puts doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_data)
```

some ajax requests running afterwards on `bet.hkjc.com` site.